# Autofac RegisterGeneric works in unit test but not in application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 6 (Framework 4.6.1) application with Autofac version 4.0.0-rc1-177.

In my Startup.cs, I call an AutofacLoader I've made:

```
var container = Core.DI.AutofacLoader.Configure(services).Build();
```

The AutofacLoader class:

```
public class AutofacLoader
{
    public static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register the DI modules through AutoFac
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">IServiceCollection to register the modules on</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ContainerBuilder Configure(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterModule<LogRequestsModule>();
        //Core
        builder.RegisterModule(new Core.ServiceModules.AutoMapperModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new Core.ServiceModules.ServicesModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new DAL.ServicesModules.IBSRepositoriesModule());

        //Dieet
        builder.RegisterModule(new Dieet.Core.ServiceModules.AutoMapperModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new Dieet.Core.ServiceModules.ServicesModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new Dieet.DAL.ServicesModules.DieetRepositoriesModule());

        //builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        if (services == null)
        {
            Container = builder.Build();
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Populate(services);

        }
        return builder;
    }
}
```

My IBS.Core.ServicesModules.ServiceModule class (which when I put a breakpoint in this class, gets called when launching my app, so by the AutofacLoader class):

```
namespace IBS.Core.ServiceModules
{
    public class ServicesModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(PaginatedSearchViewModel<>)).As(typeof(IPaginatedSearchViewModel<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
}
```

My xunit test (with FluentAssertions) that passes:

```
public class ServiceModulesTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void ShouldBeInstantiatable()
    {
        AutofacLoader.Configure(null);
        var container = AutofacLoader.Container;
        var instance = container.Resolve<IPaginatedSearchViewModel<PatientViewModel>>();

        instance.Should().BeOfType<PaginatedSearchViewModel<PatientViewModel>>();
    }
}
```

But when I run the application, in one of my API controllers, I've got for example, this method:

```
    [HttpGet("patienten")]
    public async Task<PagedResult<PatientViewModel>> GetPatientsAsync(IPaginatedSearchViewModel<PatientFilters> vm)
    {
        return await _infohosService.GetAllPatientsWithDossiersAndVerpleegperiodesAsync(vm);
    }
```

This fails in the browser with the response: Cannot resolve the Interface.

When I change the IPaginatedSearchViewModel to the concrete class in the parameters myself:

```
    [HttpGet("patienten")]
    public async Task<PagedResult<PatientViewModel>> GetPatientsAsync(PaginatedSearchViewModel<PatientFilters> vm)
    {
        return await _infohosService.GetAllPatientsWithDossiersAndVerpleegperiodesAsync(vm);
    }
```

The API works.

**So my questions:**

1. Why does my unit test pass? (I'm new to unit testing, so maybe I've done something wrong here?)
2. How can I make Autofac resolve this Interface too, because it works fine for all my Services, Repositories, IDbContext, ...?

Comment: 1. Because you directly call `Resolve` and it returns an instance
2. Are you sure that it will work at all? I'm not sure if asp.net mvc 6 uses DI container on model binding stage (if you're sure - share the link - i never heard about it). What I know is that you need to write your custom model binder which will know how to instantiate your interface. And this custom binder could be injected by some other classes.

Comment: You may want to retitle / retag your question to get more eyes on this. ASP.NET Core owns the hooks where DI runs now, not Autofac anymore. Autofac just serves as the container ASP.NET Core uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure if asp.net mvc 6 uses DI container on model binding stage

This is indeed the problem. I've Google'd some more and didn't find that MVC 6 uses the DI container in the model binding stage.

Solved by using the concrete class in the method.